# Multiplicating a matrix with a vector results in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, lsa

I have a document-term matrix:

```
document_term_matrix <- as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control = list(stemming = FALSE, stopwords=FALSE, minWordLength=3, removeNumbers=TRUE, removePunctuation=TRUE )))
```

For this document-term matrix, I've calculated the local term- and global term weighing as follows:

```
lw_tf <- lw_tf(document_term_matrix)
gw_idf <- gw_idf(document_term_matrix)
```

`lw_tf` is a matrix with the same dimensionality as the document-term-matrix (*n*x*m*) and `gw_idf` is a vector of size *n*. However, when I run:

```
tf_idf <- lw_tf * gw_idf
```

The dimensionality of `tf_idf` is again *n*x*m*.

Originally, I would not expect this multiplication to work, as the dimensionalities are not conformable. However, given this output I now expect the dimensionality of `gw_idf` to be *m*x*m*. Is this indeed the case? And if so: what happened to the `gw_idf` vector of size `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is done in R by using `%*%`, not `*` (the latter is just element-wise multiplication). Your reasoning is partially correct, you were just using the wrong symbols.

About the matrix multiplication, a matrix multiplication is only possible if the second dimension of the first matrix is the same as the first dimensions of the second matrix. The resulting dimensions is the dim1 of first matrix by the dim2 of the second matrix.

In your case, you're telling us you have a `1 x n` matrix multiplied by a `n x m` matrix, which should result in a `1 x m`  matrix. You can check such case in this example:

```
a <- matrix(runif(100, 0 , 1), nrow = 1, ncol = 100)
b <- matrix(runif(100 * 200, 0, 1), nrow = 100, ncol = 200)

c <- a %*% b
dim(c)
[1] 1 200
```

Now, about your specific case, I don't really have this package that makes term-documents (would be nice of you to provide an easily reproducible example!), but if you're multiplying a `nxm` matrix element-wise (you're using `*`, like I said in the beginning) by a `nx1` array, the result does not make sense. Either your variable `gw_idf` is not an array at all (maybe it's just a scalar) or you're simply making a wrong conclusion.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I stated the dimensions incorrectly before. I have changed the dimensions now. The fact that an element-wise multiplication is conducted explains the answer.

Comment: No problem! That's a great question for newcomers.